# Installing Perl/Tk for texdoctk

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, texdoctk

I'm trying to install Perl/Tk for `texdoctk`, and I used `cpan -i Tk` to see OK sign.

```
cpan -i Tk

...
2level/perllocal.pod
  SREZIC/Tk-804.033.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
```

However, when I execute the texdoctk, I have this error message.

```
texdoctk algorithms
Can't locate Tk.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Tk module) (@INC contains: ...
) at /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin/texdoctk line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin/texdoctk line 15.
```

What might be wrong? During the installation, the two lines are added to the .bashrc:

```
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/Users/smcho/perl5\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/smcho/perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
```

I use Mac OS X 10.10, and this is the results from `perl -V`.

```
  @INC:
    /Users/smcho/.opam/system/lib/perl5
    /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.18
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.18
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2
    /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/5.18
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18
```

Comment: Is `/Users/smcho/perl5` in @INC when you run `perl -V`

Comment: @Ben Grimm: Nope, I updated the post.

Comment: If you set `PERL5LIB` to include `/Users/smcho/perl5` where you installed Tk, it would be. Try `perldoc -lm Tk` after setting `PERL5LIB`.

Comment: @Ben Grimm: What might be `the path`?

Comment: Newer versions of `cpan` will prompt you if you don't have permission to write to the system Perl directories; you can choose to either bootstrap `local::lib` (the default) or use `sudo`. If you choose `local::lib`, `PERL_MB_OPT` and `PERL_MM_OPT` will be automatically set in your `.bashrc`. Since you're installing modules outside of the system Perl, you need to tell Perl where to look, which you can do with `PERL5LIB` as Ben Grimm pointed out.

Comment: Try locating `Tk.pm` within `/Users/smcho/perl5` and adding the containing path

Comment: @Ben Grimm: I updated your answer, and it finds the Tk now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're installing modules outside of the default paths, you'll need to set `PERL5LIB` to match:

```
PERL5LIB="/Users/smcho/perl5/lib/perl5"; export PERL5LIB
```

Comment: @prosseek Perhaps try `PERL5LIB="/Users/smcho/perl5/lib/perl5"`