# cygwin perl cpan installations in wrong directory

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan

I have a cygwin perl setup and i do a `cpan App::cpanminus` or `cpan ExtUtils::Config` i get a response that the packages are installed successfully,

but cpanm is not in path its on `~/Perl5/bin`
and i dont know where `ExtUtils::Config` is installed
if i do a `perl -e 'use ExtUtils::Config;'` i get an error that it is not found

I feel this is a cpan configuration error but dont know what it is or how to fix it, can some one help me in this regard?

**Edit:**

Output of
`echo 'o conf' | cpan | perl -ne'print if /^\s*(make|mbuild)(pl)?_/'`

```
make_arg           []
make_install_arg   []
make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/make]
makepl_arg         []
mbuild_arg         []
mbuild_install_arg []
mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
mbuildpl_arg       []
```

and output of `perl -le'print "$_=$ENV{$_}" for grep /^PERL/, keys %ENV'`

```
PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base "/home/<user>/perl5"
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/<user>/perl5
```

Comment: Are the environment variables `PERL_MB_OPT` and `PERL_MM_OPT` set?

Comment: Please add the output of `echo 'o conf' | cpan | perl -ne'print if /^\s*(make|mbuild)(pl)?_/'` and the output of `perl -le'print "$_=$ENV{$_}" for grep /^PERL/, keys %ENV'` to your question.

Comment: You *might* have configured cpan to [bootstrap local::lib](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32726324/176646), although in that case I would also expect to see the `PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT` variable set.

Comment: there is no `PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT` in `.bashrc` and I ran `o conf init` and it didnt prompt me anything about `local::lib`.
maybe i could add that manually in `.bashrc` and also update `PATH` variable to include `~/perl5/bin`.

Comment: (Use @username in replies to other people so they get notified. It's a fluke that I noticed you provided the requested information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following tell the module installers (ExtUtils::MakeMaker and Module::Build respectively) to install the modules in directory other than the one `perl` looks in:

```
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/<user>/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base "/home/<user>/perl5"
```

Either unset these variables (to install the modules in their "proper" place), or tell `perl` to look for modules in that directory.

```
export PERL5LIB="$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5"
```

Comment: also @ThisSuitIsBlackNot 's question helped, i added these three manually to .bashrc

export PATH="$PATH:/home/<user>/perl5/bin"                                        
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/<user>/perl5"; export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT;             
PERL5LIB="/home/<user>/perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB+:}${PERL5LIB}"; export PERL5LIB;